# How to pass complex data in D3

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js, svg

I want to pass two values through d3 because i need both of them at the same time in two different svg elements

so what i do is

```
data1={
       "1":
             '["Not Informed","8"]',
       "2":
             '["Somewhat Informed","24"]',
       "3":
             '["Informed","64"]'
};
console.log(data1[3])
```

so the output comes :      ["Informed","64"]

So i haven't showed you my d3 code so please tell me how to print both of them differently rest I'll figure out.
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by print both of them diffrently?

Comment: what i mean referring to above question 'i want to use INformed and 64' separately at the same time. and I dnt want to pass two variables that is y i used only one complex variable

Comment: `console.log(data1[3][0])//will give you informed and console.log(data1[3][1])//will give 64`

Comment: Is your gol get the first element of data1[3] in a chart and in the second one get the second element of data1[3]?

Comment: what happens is when i use what u advice lets say i used console,log(data1[3][0])) It surprisingly prints ' [ ' when use data1[3][1] it prints ' I ' thats what is happening

Comment: Try to parse data1 as a JSON variable like this: JSON.parse(data1)

Comment: Exactly @Giordano Please refer to my answer let me know your views

Comment: Great! please let flag the comment as useful if you have been helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the guidance but i think i got my answer

It is a syntax error
to get through data1[3][1] syntax would be

```
data1={"1":["Not Informed","8"],"2":["Somewhat Informed","24"],"3":["Informed","64"]};
```

It works totally  i am not sure what happened when i use the above(reffering to question) code to declare that array .. If anybody can figure that out please reply to this answer